# python, write dictionary of varying value lengths to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I need to write a dictionary with varying value lengths to a csv file. So far I have (left) but need (right) - how do I do this?
[image]

So far my code is:

```
somedict = dict(folder='path here..', data=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], options=['red', 'yellow', 'pink', 'green'])
with open(outfile_csv, 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(somedict.keys())
    w.writerow(somedict.values())
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hmm, "how do I generate a csv file akin to that shown on the right hand side [given a dictionary of varying value-lengths as shown]".

Comment: You need to call `writerow` once for each row you want to write, i.e. apparently 5 times in your example. You called it two times, that's why you got two rows in the output.

Answer (score 0):

If your data structure is flexible, this would be easier to handle:

```
data_to_write = [
    {'folder': 'path...', 'data': 1, 'options': 'red'}, 
    {'folder': 'path...', 'data': 2, 'options': 'yellow'},
    ...
]
```

Comment: Ok I think I see where you're going with this, could you give a code example which generates the CSV similar to the RHS image, thanks